# Did my frame just break?

Tags: frames, damage

Bike: Raymon HardRay E-Nine 6.0

I just finished adjusting the gear shifting for my first time.
As I went for a test drive the chain immediately slipped down.
Then I saw this.
[image: close up from frame without wheel]
[image: Back frame not broken]
[image: Broken Frame]

First I thought the frame just broke but it also seems like a part which can be replaced. I'm a bit confused as it just broke and I just noticed it because the chain went down.

- So can this be replaced?
- Is the whole frame broken?
- What part is this?
- It looks a bit like a predetermined breaking point, is it actually one?

Comment: Regarding how it broke, you probably misadjusted the limit screws on your derailleur and the chain got wedged somewhere it shouldn’t be. Also, you should check your derailleur for bending or other damage. The hanger is supposed to save both the der and frame but often the der gets somewhat bent before the hanger breaks.

Comment: Undo those screws you see in the second picture. If the black bit you see in the first falls off, then it's just the hanger.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I **think** its just the hanger that has broken.  They're not cheap, but they cost less than a new frame.

Keep the old bits and reassemble them, and then compare with https://wheelsmfg.com/derailleur-hangers/all-derailleur-hangers.html to find the right one.

You might be able to shortcut the process some by brand, at https://wheelsmfg.com/derailleur-hangers/manufacturers.html

Keep the little bolts too, the replacement may not come with new ones.  You can buy the hanger from your Local Bike Shop, or perhaps direct from dealer.  The wheels-mfg ones are good quality aftermarket options.

---

As for why it broke in the first place - this is a deliberately weaker link that is supposed to save the more-expensive derailleur and frame from damage if something is really wrong.

You said the chain "slipped down" which suggests the limit screws did not stop the chain from jumping off the cassette and possibly bound up, tearing the derailleur clean-off.

Check your chain and rear derailleur for damage too -there may be a side-plate sticking out or a twist or even a stiff-link.

On reassembling, ensure the limit screws stop the chain from moving off the cassette in both directions, and then leave them alone while you do indexing.

Good luck !

Answer (score 8):

I think it is a [derailleur hanger](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/a/3665/38270). Try to unscrew those two small screws from the inner side to release the rest. They might be 2 mm hex screws or something similar.

You can ask the vendor (distributor or manufacturer). If it is replaceable, you will have to order the part with them anyway.

Answer (score -3):

Short answer: the frame is broken and cannot be repaired.

If what is pictured is the frame, then it cannot be replaced. The frame looks like it is aluminium so it cannot be repaired.
There is a small chance that this is only the derailleur hanger: Are there some screws which would remove parts of what is broken? Can you take a picture from another angle showing more of the rear part of the bike?

Comment: Added 2 more pictures. So is it the hanger ? And can i just buy the hanger ? How does something like this break did I tighten it too much maybe ?

Comment: As others have answered as well it seems its only the hanger. Try to remove the part and take all of them to the bike shop they should be able to order a new one for you. As you know the exact model of your bike you could try to look up the part number and order it yourself. But this can be challenging there are so many models. As to why it breaks (if it is the hanger): to avoid damaging your frame ;)